# How to take derivative of summation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm having issues figuring out how find the derivative of L wrt $c_{ni}$ in this case.  $a_n$ and $c_{ni}$ are both vectors. Here's what I have so far:

$$L = \sum_{n=0}^N\| a_n- \sum_{i=0}^Bc_{ni}d_i\|^2$$
$$L' =  \sum_{n=0}^N\|2* \sum_{i=0}^Bc_{ni}d_i * d_i\|$$
$$L' =  \sum_{n=0}^N\|2* \sum_{i=0}^Bc_{ni} * \sum_{i=0}^Bd_i^2\| $$
$$L' =  \sum_{n=0}^N\|2* B * c_{ni} * B * d_i^2\| $$
$$L' =  N * \|2* B * c_{ni} * B * d_i^2\| $$

But this doesn't seem right... I'm not sure what to do with the $d_i$ in the first step of the derivative.

Comment: Where's the $x$ dependence?

Comment: @JackyChong updated.

Comment: @user1883614 You are taking the derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @hardmath and JackyChong - updated. sorry about that!

Comment: You can and are welcome to edit your question's actual wording itself, instead of appending a statement starting with "Edit:" which corrects the inaccurate wording. Since revisions of edit history are available anyway, keeping the inaccurate wording in place is superfluous, misguiding and annoying.

Comment: @hardmath these are vectors that I am dealing with so the magnitude.

Comment: After a request for additional information (from @JackyChong) has been satisfied by the OP via submission of an updated question version, those information request comments, which had been addressed by the edit, and replies to them are now deemed superfluous and shall be deleted by their respective posters.

Comment: @user1883614 please also edit the subject matter of your latest comment into your question body.

Comment: @dbanet i think I did!

Comment: We are told that $c_{ni}$ is a vector, not a scalar, which makes it dubious to propose differentiating with respect to $c_{ni}$.  As for what to do with $d_i$ in the differentiation, the expression would make more sense if $c_{ni}$ were scalar and $d_i$ the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n$ be the matrix whose $i$th column is $c_{ni}$, and let 
$$
d = \begin{bmatrix} d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_B \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Note that
$$L(d) = \sum_{n=0}^N \| C_n d - a_n \|^2.$$
From the multivariable chain rule, the gradient of $L$ is
$$
\nabla L(d) = \sum_{n=0}^N 2 C_n^T(C_n d - a_n).
$$
(Here we are using the convention that the gradient is a column vector rather than a row vector.)

Comment: @hardmath Fixed it, thanks.